# How can I save image jpeg file?

Tags: java, file

In Java I'm loading binary image data from a database.

```
HttpServletRequest request = null;
//...
Integer parameter = Integer.valueOf(request.getPathInfo().substring(1));
ImageEntity image = loadImage(parameter);
byte[] binaryImageData = image.getImageData();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\img.jpg");

//How can I save binaryImageData to C:\img.jpg?
```

How can I save `binaryImageData` loaded from the db to the file `C:\img.jpg`?

Comment: So, downvoters, if the answer is too obvoiusly couldn;t you provide it?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working with my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using streams for binary data.

In your case:

```
Integer parameter = Integer.valueOf(request.getPathInfo().substring(1));
ImageEntity image = loadImage(parameter);
byte[] binaryImageData = image.getImageData();
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    "C:\\img.jpg"));
out.write(binaryImageData);
```